# Expand $(3x^2+y)^5$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

Using binomial theorem we have $\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^ky^{n-k}$ where n =5.

I tried setting it up like this:

${5 \choose 0}3x^{2k}y^{n-k}+.......+{5 \choose 5}3x^{2k}y^{n-k}$

for ex. k=2:

${5 \choose 2} 3x^4y^3 = 10 \times 3x^4y^3 = 30x^4y^3$

My answer was way off. My powers were all correct but my coefficients were way off, not even in the same ballpark. How do I go about calculating this?

Comment: Use parentheses.  The square of $3x^2$ is $(3x^2)^2=3x^2\cdot3x^2=9x^4$.

Comment: You need parenthesis ! $(3x^2)^2=9x^4$ for example.

Comment: And also to break the habit of forgetting the binomial coefficients in the generic binomial theorem, but adding them in your specific implementation. You had them where it matters, here, but it's asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/algebra-2/binomial-expansion-calculator/?i=3x%5E2%2By&n=5&steps=on) might prove to be very useful to you. Although you have been correctly guided in the comments section. You need to use parentheses correctly.

Comment: That was very clear clut

Answer (score 1):

We have: ${5\choose{0}}(3x^{2})^{5}+{5\choose{1}}(3x^{2})^{4}(y)+{5\choose{2}}(3x^{2})^{3}(y)^{2}+{5\choose{3}}(3x^{2})^{2}(y)^{3}+{5\choose{4}}(3x^{2})(y)^{4}+{5\choose{5}}(y)^{5}$

$=(1)(243x^{10})+(5)(81x^{8})(y)+(10)(27x^{6})(y^{2})+(10)(9x^{4})(y^{3})+(5)(3x^{2})(y^{4})+(1)(y^{5})$

$=243x^{10}+405x^{8}y+270x^{6}y^{2}+90x^{4}y^{3}+15x^{2}y^{4}+y^{5}$

Answer (score 0):

For the coefficients I would simply use Pascal's triangle. Then you just have to include the powers of $(3x^2)^m$ and $(3x^2)^n$ with $n+m = 5$

$\newcommand\cn[3]{\llap{#1}#2\rlap{#3}} \begin{array}{c} &&&&&&\cn{}{1}{}\\ &&&&&\cn{}{1}{}&&\cn{}{1}{}\\ &&&&\cn{}{1}{}&&\cn{}{2}{}&&\cn{}{1}{}\\ &&&\cn{}{1}{}&&\cn{}{3}{}&&\cn{}{3}{}&&\cn{}{1}{}\\ &&\cn{}{1}{}&&\cn{}{4}{}&&\cn{}{6}{}&&\cn{}{4}{}&&\cn{}{1}{}\\ &\cn{}{1}{}&&\cn{}{5}{}&&\cn{1}{}{0}&&\cn{1}{}{0}&&\cn{}{5}{}&&\cn{}{1}{}\\ \cn{}{1}{}&&\cn{}{6}{}&&\cn{1}{}{5}&&\cn{2}{}{0}&&\cn{1}{}{5}&&\cn{}{6}{}&&\cn{}{1}{} \end{array}$

For a fast calculation of the triangle, observe that the left and right most numbers are always $1$ and those in between equal the sum of the two digits above it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to raise powers of $3x^2$